# Spring batch - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated error at custom writer

Tags: spring-batch

After the writer class ends. The error occurs in spring batch execution.
all of read data is to be rollback and chunk data is not inserted to DB.

What is that mean of "Commit failed while step execution data was already updated error"? And why does occur this log?

Is it problem that may time of insert transaction in writer?

If there is one time of insert transaction(commented out to 'recordDataService.insertRecordData(recordData);', there is no problem.

**My Code :**

```
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends RecordInfo> items)  {

    log.info("########################################################");
    log.info("write");
    log.info("########################################################");

    recordInfoService.insertRecordInfo(recordInfos.get(0));

    for( RecordData recordData : recordInfos.get(0).getRecordDataList()){
                recordDataService.insertRecordData(recordData);
    }
```

**The Log of each other writer :**

```
2015-07-17 00:05:38.995  INFO 42558 --- [           main] c.s.c.b.j.c.CollectRecordItemWriter      : ########################################################
2015-07-17 00:05:38.995  INFO 42558 --- [           main] c.s.c.b.j.c.CollectRecordItemWriter      : write
2015-07-17 00:05:38.995  INFO 42558 --- [           main] c.s.c.b.j.c.CollectRecordItemWriter      : ########################################################
2015-07-17 16:34:26.921  INFO 41111 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2015-07-16 02:30:25.734  INFO 60636 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
```

**The Log of Execution :** everything was to be rollback

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
Step collectRecordStep 
WriteCount: 0
ReadCount: 14
ReadSkipCount: 0
Commits: 1
SkipCount: 0
Rollbacks: 14
Filter: 0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Are you using ORM (e.g. Hibernate)? If yes, do you control the time of the flush? take a look at the http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html especially the source https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.java

Comment: No, I am using myBatis

Comment: What is the concern here?  As the log states, the commit failed so Spring Batch is reverting the StepExecution to it's previous state (aka before this transaction).  That's what it's supposed to do.